# Session Timeout extend in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, session, timeout, extend

How to extend the session timeout?
I tried entering:

```
Session.Timeout = 720;
```

In `formLoad` and also tried in `webconfig`:

```
<system.web>
    <sessionState 
     mode="InProc"
     cookieless="true"
     timeout="720" />
</system.web>
```

But still it times out after 10 minutes. Can anyone help about this issue?

Comment: web.config is the right place. Can you post your changes?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [Microsoft Technet article](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/2a42175f-8756-4409-8db4-8c08b33b810b.mspx?mfr=true). Check if it suits your needs.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState 
         cookieless="true" 
         timeout="20">
     </sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might see this article, I haven't used it but a time ago I needed something like this to use in a webservice and I finished with another approach. It could be useful to you:

[The Defibrillator: Keeping ASP.NET Session Alive Ad Infinitum](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/session/Session_Defibrillator.aspx)