# Extend the session in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session-timeout

How to extend the session time automatically and how session cycle works in asp.net?

Answer (score 4):

The **Session State** is extended when the user makes a request based on the *unique string* (provided that the session has not yet ceased).  If the session time is expired, and a request is made based on the previous, then a new session will start and the form state (data that exists on form) will be submitted.

To extend the session state, go to your web.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<configuration>
 <system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
   <sessionState timeout="90" cookieless="AutoDetect" />
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The attribute

```
timeout="90"
```

sets a 90 minutes expiration time for the Session state.  If there is no response within the time frame, the Session state is removed.

The attribute

```
cookieless="AutoDetect"
```

will store the unique string into the cookie, if the user does not have the cookie, it will utilize it within the url.

Comment: Session state timeout is in minutes, not seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at following

[Session Timeout extend in Asp.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266536/session-timeout-extend-in-asp-net)

A must read if you are newb
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972429.aspx

Answer (score 1):

another way to alert the user that session has expired
 http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/AspNetAlertSessionExpire-c230a148